# How do I install sway on Ubuntu

Tags: xorg, wayland

How do I get `sway` installed on my system and configured on boot? Arch has this package in the repository.

Comment: What does the purge have to do with sway?

Comment: The answer provided by [user:FliegendeWurst] instructs installation (following the official guide), so please mark it as accepted or lay down why this doesn't work in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

An [unofficial](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/1197) [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~samoilov-lex/+archive/ubuntu/sway) `ppa:samoilov-lex/sway` exists (compatible with **Ubuntu 19.04+**):

Run following commands in order to install Sway from the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samoilov-lex/sway
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sway
```

After installing, it should be possible to start Sway from the login screen.

#### See also

For installing Sway on distributions (that don't have a Sway package available in their official repositories) see the wiki page on [Unsupported Packages](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/wiki/Unsupported-packages).

Comment: Unfortunately not working anymore... :(

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: That there is no release file on bionic.

Comment: Concise answer. I edited and improved clarity (compatibility) as well as added the _See also_ section for further information.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **Snap** named *Sway* that can be installed from *Snap Store* :

```bsh
sudo snap install sway --beta
```

Note: as of writing this answer (2019-Nov-27) the snap is marked **experimental** and seems in *beta* stage.

#### See also

- [installation instruction](https://snapcraft.io/install/sway/ubuntu)
- GitHub repository: [sd-hd/sway-snap](https://github.com/sd-hd/sway-snap)
- author of this snap: [sdhd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3632420/sdhd)

Comment: Succeeded installation on **Bionic Beaver (18.04 LTS)** with following message: `INFO snap "sway" has bad plugs or slots: dbus (cannot find attribute 'bus')`

Comment: "sway (beta) 1.3.0-1 from Sascha Dewald (sdhd) installed" with no error message on 18.04 LTS.

Comment: However, this does not make Sway available as a desktop manager on the login menu, making this a bit of an exercise to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Ubuntu Sway Remix](https://ubuntusway.com/) from their ISO image. I think they also have [meta packages](https://github.com/Ubuntu-Sway/ubuntu-sway-meta) available.